# Coloring the elements of Listview

Tags: xamarin.android

I want to color the background of the first item in listview .

Where it takes a different color from the rest of the elements of listView

Comment: Hi , you can bind a view model for listview , and setting the first item soure with background color . Then the first item of listview will show different .

Comment: I have updated an answer with xamarin android and xamarin forms how to achieve that . Also share the sample there . If answer be helpful and have solved that , please do not forget to accept it as answer( click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **Xamarin Android** , we can custom a **Adapter** for ListView to achieve that . Modify `GetView` method to set background color when `position == 0` as follow :

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    var item = items[position];

    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) // no view to re-use, create new
        view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.CustomView, null);
    view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Text1).Text = item.Heading;
    view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Text2).Text = item.SubHeading + " items";
    view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.Image).SetImageResource(item.ImageResourceId);

    // Here set background color when position == 0 

    if (position == 0)
    {
        view.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Red);
    }

    return view;
}
```

The effect :

[image]

In **Xamarin Forms**, we can create a **Item** class for listview each cell .

```
public class Item
{
    public Color DefaultColor { set; get; }
    public string DisplayName { set; get; }
}
```

Then create a **ViewModel** class as follow :

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<Item> Items { set; get; }
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Items = new List<Item>();
        Items.Add(new Item() { DefaultColor = Color.Red, DisplayName = "First Item" });
        Items.Add(new Item() { DisplayName = "Second Item" }) ;
        Items.Add(new Item() { DisplayName = "Third Item" });
        Items.Add(new Item() { DisplayName = "Fourth Item" });
        Items.Add(new Item() { DisplayName = "Fifth Item" });
    }
}
```

In **Xaml** , `ListView` setted as follow :

```
<ListView x:Name="EmployeeView" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout  BackgroundColor="{Binding DefaultColor}">
                    <Label Text="{Binding DisplayName}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Last setting `ViewModel` for `ListView` in **ContentPage** :

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var viewModel = new ViewModel();
    EmployeeView.ItemsSource = viewModel.Items;
}
```

The effect :

[image]

Sample for reference : **[Android ListView sample Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8hwqka06wdb2xr3/AppAndroidListView.rar?dl=0)** , **[Xamarin Forms ListView Sample Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vvugc5hyei743z0/AppListView.rar?dl=0)**